# How to initialize array with strings and how to calculate the char value of double characters

Tags: c

How can I initialize this as array

```
char keyboard[] = {'C', "C#", 'D', "D#", 'E', 'F', "F#", 'G', "G#", 'A', "A#", 'B'};
```

Also, what would the char value of C#, D# and the other double characrters be because I intend to use them to boolean compared other variables.

Answer (score 0):

`"C#"` etc are not single characters but whole strings (null-terminated). You can't have an array of characters and an array of strings at the same time, mixed with each other.

Probably you want something like an array of strings `const char* keyboard[]  = {"C", "C#", ...`.

If you wish to compare them with other variables, then use `strcmp(keyboard[i], other)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `"C#"`, `"F#"` etc. will be compiled into C string(array of chars terminated by zero character `'\0'`).

If you want to store these texts in array you need an array of C strings, for example

```
const char * keyboard[] = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"};
```

To compare C strings you can use `strcmp()` method (ref. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).